# Hive 1.0 - REMOTE MySQL Metastore configuration

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, metastore, apache-hive

on EMR 4.2 - Hive 1.0 version, I want to connect to a remote mysql metastore.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://hive-metastore-remotemysql.aws.com:9083</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

This remorte metastore is on Hive .12 and I still want to connect to same metastore from a new cluster. Because of the new hive-site.xml format I cannot give proper value to metastore-uris. As 9083 deoes not exist on remote. Id I give local then hive does not know about all databases.

Anyone has faced this and solved?

Thanks!